# Copying array of sprites in Visual C# and XNA

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am developing a Uno card game using Visual C# 2010 and XNA 4.0. I have created an array of 108 element of all the Uno Cards as the array elements.

Now I want to assign random 7 cards to each of the 4 players at the begining of the game.
So I am creating a random number and then assigning the card at that nmber to a player.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            int r = rnd.Next(108);
            if (vis[r] != 1)  //vis[] is an array to checkk visited elements
            {

              //  u[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("toString.Allcards[r]");
                u[i]=Content.Load<Texture2D>(ToString("Allcards[r]"));
            }
```

This is not working, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Allcards[r]" holds the textures for the cards (ie, Allcards[1] == "Ace of Spades" and theres a texture called Ace of Spades in your project), you probably want this instead:

```
u[i]=Content.Load<Texture2D>(Allcards[r]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                int r = rnd.Next(108);
                if (vis[r] != 1)  //vis[] is an array to checkk visited elements
                {

                  //  u[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("toString.Allcards[r]");
                    u[i]=Content.Load<Texture2D>(Allcards[r].ToString());
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `Content.Load<Texture2D>(Allcards[r]);` assuming that Allcards is an array of strings. If Allcards is an array of Texture2D objects, then `Content.Load` is unnecessary because you've already loaded it; you can use `u[i] = Allcards[r]`.

Having said that, you probably don't want to just give the texture to the player; you'll want to give them the actual card. I'd suggest creating a Card class and assigning textures to that, along with some useful info like an ID, and maybe some properties to explain what it does.